Updating an SQL Server project in Visual Studio
When creating an SQL Server project, the database is imported. Next, you can deploy the database on the server, but you cannot get changes from it to the project (the "Import -> Database" option is not available). Is it possible to get changes from the database to an already imported project? Or is an approach like "Code first" used here?

The command is Schema Compare. There's no "Code First", the code is the SQL commands

The Schema Compare tool is available from the VS main menu under Tools-->SQL Server-->New Schema Comparison

You want to rightclick on the project and choose "schema compare" from the context menu.
Remember to flip the source and target with the double arrow icon so changes from the server goes into the solution.
